# Manually decide when to display certain data in plot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted data from three experiments in the same plot but I would like to display them sequentially (e.g. first of all I show a plot with data from Experiment 1, then I add data from Experiment 2 to the previous plot and finally I add data from Experiment 3, so that data from all 3 experiments appear in the same plot). Are there any commands in ggplot2 that can help me do this? Here is how things are visualised now:

`df <- data.frame(Experiment=c("E1", "E2", "E3"), Result=c(4.5,9, 19))`

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Experiment, y=Result, fill=Experiment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blu", "yellow"))
```

[image: Current visualization]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Facets? Grouped bars? A different type of chart? As it stands, this question is more broadly about data visualization style—try to figure out more specifically what you want, and folks can help you put it together or debug your code. We don't have enough of your data to do much more than the chart you already have. The `ggplot2` docs and the [R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/portfolio/ggplot2-package/) have lots of examples of what's possible

Comment: I have already taken facets into consideration but I don't think it's what I want, I am looking for an interactive rather than static solution. Basically, I want to know whether I can show or hide the bars related to E1, E2 or E3 so that I can focus more on one set or the other during my presentation. Does this clarify things?

Comment: Have you searched for "interactive ggplot"? I'd also suggest adding the word "interactive"  in your question. "Manual" seems like you want to manually write code for each graph. You can do this with `Shiny`, maybe `ggplotly`, you could make a animated chart with `gganimate`. It will depend on the format, do you want this to be viewed in a browser? Interactive web app? Or maybe just a function in R that a user can run with different arguments to produce each plot?

Comment: No, doesn't clarify much, because we still don't have enough data or code to help you finish building it. Building an interactive chart requires a different set of tools that weren't mentioned in the question. It will be easier to help once you've gotten more of the project started, and know what tools you'd like to use